# Prove a collinearity

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $\vartriangle ABC$ be a triangle with circumcenter $O$, circumcircle $(c)$ and altitude $AL$.

The tangents to $B$ and $C$ have $D$ as a common point.

Let $E \equiv AD \cap BC$.

Let $c_1$ be the circumcircle of $\vartriangle BOC$ and $K \equiv c_1 \cap AO$.

Also, let $M \equiv DL \cap c_1$.

Prove that $M,E,K$ are collinear.

[image]

Comment: I added a diagram to make the construction less hard to follow, but what are your attempts?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $R$ is the circumradius of $ABC$. By angle chasing $D$ belongs to the circumcircle of $BOC$, having $OD$ as a diameter. In particular there are many equal angles:

[image]

The green angle equals $\pi-2B$, so the blue angle ($\widehat{DMK}$, we are not assuming that $E\in MK$, that is what we want to prove) equals $A-(\pi-2B)=B-C$ and the yellow angle equals $A$. In particular $MD$ is the angle bisector of $\widehat{BMC}$ and $\frac{BL}{LC}=\frac{BM}{MC}=\frac{c\cos B}{b\cos C}=\frac{\tan C}{\tan B}$.
The circumradius of $OBC$ equals $\frac{R}{2\cos A}$, so $CK=\frac{R\sin(2B)}{\cos A}$. Similarly $CD=BD=R\tan(A)$.
Moreover $BM=CD\frac{BL}{LC}=R\frac{\tan(A)\tan(B)}{\tan(C)}$, so $\frac{BM}{CK}=\frac{\sin(A)}{2\tan(C)\cos^2(B)}$.
Now it is enough to compute $\frac{BE}{EC}$ in terms of $A,B,C$ to prove the collinearity of $M,E,K$.

Comment: Nice solution, but can you explain how you find $\dfrac{BE}{EC}$ in terms of $A,B,C$ ?

Comment: @knm: by exploiting areas / by the sine theorem.

Comment: Can we have a solution without trigonometry?